# Cannot put customer data in sparkpost email

Tags: c#, sparkpost

I'm attempting to create a Sparkpost email where the template generates to say the recipient's name like "Hello, David" for example. For reference I'm making a call from a web app that uses C#.
The sparkpost website doesn't seem to have any information on doing things like this. Can someone give me some pointers please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you would put something like this in your template:

```
Hello, {{address.name}}
```

Then in your recipient's array do something like this

```
    "recipients": [
    {
      "address": {
        "email": "david@domain.com",
        "name": "David"
      }
              :
              :
  ]
```

Here is an article I wrote a while back that may help:

https://www.sparkpost.com/blog/advanced-email-templates/

I also have various Template example here written in Java incase it can help:

https://github.com/SparkPost/java-sparkpost/tree/master/apps/sparkpost-samples-app/src/main/java/com/sparkpost/samples